# Inserting a string after each character in a cell containing a string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell containing a string - B1 = "HelloWorld". What I'd like to do is, between each letter in the string, enter the string  so, for example,

B2 = `"H<pause>E<pause>L<pause>L<pause>O<pause>W<pause>O<pause>R<pause>L<pause>D".`

I've tried '=replace(A7, "", 7, "")" but the second parameter has to be greater than 1.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B1,"(.)","$1<pause>")
```

The capture group [`( )`] is any character [`.`] output as that capture group [`$1`] with `<pause>`.